# Access query, grouped sum of 2 columns where either column contains values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Another team has an Access database that they use to track call logs. It's very basic, really just a table with a few lookups, and they enter data directly in the datasheet view. They've asked me to assist with writing a report to sum up their calls by week and reason and I'm a bit stumped on this problem because I'm not an Access guy by any stretch.

The database consists of two core tables, one holding the call log entries (Calls) and one holding the lookup list of call reasons (ReasonsLookup). Relevant table structures are:

```
Calls
-----
ID         (autonumber, PK)
DateLogged (datetime)
Reason     (int, FK to ReasonLookup.ID)
Reason 2   (int, FK to ReasonLookup.ID)

ReasonLookup
------------
ID         (autonumber PK)
Reason     (text)
```

What they want is a report that looks like this:

```
WeekNum      Reason                 Total
-------      ----------             -----
10           Eligibility Request    24
10           Extension Request      43
10           Information Question   97
11           Eligibility Request    35
11           Information Question   154
...          ... etc                ...
```

My problem is that there are TWO columns in the Calls table, because they wanted to log a primary and secondary reason for receiving the call, i.e. someone calls for reason A and while on the phone also requests something under reason B. Every call will have a primary reason column value (Calls.Reason not null) but not necessarily a secondary reason column value (Calls.[Reason 2] is often null).

What they want is, for each WeekNum, a single (distinct) entry for each possible Reason, and a Total of how many times that Reason was used in *either* the Calls.Reason or Calls.[Reason 2] column for that week. So in the example above for Eligibility Request, they want to see one entry for Eligibility Request for the week and count every record in Calls that for that week that has Calls.Reason = Eligibility Request OR Calls.[Reason 2] = Eligibility Request.

What is the best way to approach a query that will display as shown above? Ideally this is a straight query, no VBA required. They are non-technical so the simpler and easier to maintain the better if possible.

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is your week number an arbitrary number or does it correspond to the week of the year?

Comment: Access doesn't allow `union` in subqueries.  Any possibility you can use a different database?  It would be easier.

Comment: @paqogomez It's actually a datestamp and I used Format() to extract the week number for the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No they are simply a help desk and we don't really have the infrastructure to support development for the org in general. I'm a developer but I'm the only one and I work primarily on one application, and they are in a different shop. I'm doing it as a favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" approach would be to use a `union all` query as a subquery to create a set of weeks and reasons, however Access doesn't support this, but what you can do that should work is to first define a query to make the union and then use that query as a source for the "main" query.

So the first query would be

```
SELECT datepart("ww",datelogged) as week, Reason from calls
UNION ALL 
SELECT datepart("ww",datelogged), [Reason 2] from calls;
```

Save this as `UnionQuery` and make another query `mainQuery`:

```
SELECT uq.week, rl.reason, Count(*) AS Total
FROM UnionQuery AS uq
INNER JOIN reasonlookup AS rl ON uq.reason = rl.id
GROUP BY uq.week, rl.reason;
```

Comment: From what I can tell this seemed to work, but its not my data. I've passed it off to the other team to test tomorrow and see if it worked. If so I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Inelegant (in my opinion), but the way to get this done in MS Access.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree it's inelegant, but we work with what's available. Access leaves a lot to be wished for in my opinion.

Comment: To be fair, this is a table design issue. Reasons should have been normalized in a separate one-to-many table to Calls or in same Calls table in one field with an Importance (Primary/Secondary) field. Of course with another SQL dialect you may cleverly script all this in one query but that will involve subqueries which may not be elegant with performance and readability impact. So, we can all jump on the Access "toy" database bandwagon or understand all software has limitations. Plus, you should see what people do with Excel! Yikes!

Comment: @Parfait You are right, I kicked myself when this request came in. I built the original db in a few minutes when one of their team members came to me specifically wanting an Access db. I did the quick-and-dirty thinking it would be done and gone, but I should have known I would be signing on to support it! In hindsight it should have been a separate table, but that would have required a proper form, and he was happy just entering data directly into the table, so that's what he got. Oh well. Luckily if things get too hairy maintaining it is not officially my job! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Union query to append individual Group By Aggregate queries for both Reason and Reason 2:

```
SELECT DatePart("ww", Calls.DateLogged) As WeekNum, ReasonLookup.Reason, 
       Sum(Calls.ID) As [Total]
FROM Calls 
INNER JOIN Calls.Reason = ReasonLookup.ID
GROUP BY DatePart("ww", Calls.DateLogged) As WeekNum, ReasonLookup.Reason;    
UNION
SELECT DatePart("ww", Calls.DateLogged) As WeekNum, ReasonLookup.Reason, 
       Sum(Calls.ID) As [Total]
FROM Calls 
INNER JOIN Calls.[Reason 2] = ReasonLookup.ID
GROUP BY DatePart("ww", Calls.DateLogged) As WeekNum, ReasonLookup.Reason;
```

[DatePart()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php) outputs the specific date's week number in the calendar year. Also, `UNION` as opposed to `UNION ALL` prevents duplicate rows from appearing.

Comment: This will produce duplicate rows for a given reason.

Comment: Good catch if Totals differ, there won't be duplicates per my last sentence. And most likely they will differ. The OP would need to run another query to correct for it.